# Mysterious LoadError on installed gem with bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

The following terminal session explains the problem.  I don't understand how it's possible that I'm getting a load error on an installed gem.

The sailthru gem which isn't loading is something I installed today, which may be relevant.  I verified it was installed to the same location as my other gems, and I also tried restarting the Terminal app.  I'm using rbenv on a mac.  However, I have not installed a new version of ruby for at least a few weeks, and have been using it daily until now without any issues.

Thanks for any help.

```
$ gem list | grep sailthru
sailthru (1.1.2)
sailthru-client (4.0.1, 2.0.0)
$ cat Gemfile | grep sailthru
gem 'sailthru'
$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep sailthru
    sailthru (1.1.2)
  sailthru
$ bundle exec thin start
Using rack adapter
/Users/jg/Dropbox/sinatra/app.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- sailthru (LoadError)
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'sailthru'
=> true
irb(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `sailthru` file to require.

You should take a look at the [project page](https://github.com/ienders/sailthru).

`require 'sailthru'`

should be

`require 'sailthru/client'`

Hope this helps.

#### EDIT

Just noticed the last part where you gave `irb` output.

The `sailthru.rb` file is part of the `sailthru-client` gem. It is working through `irb` because `irb` is not loaded via `bundle exec`. This means that every gem installed is available in `irb`.

To fix this (if you need that `sailthru-client` gem in your app. Add `gem 'sailthru-client'` to your gem file. Do a `bundle install`, then run your `bundle exec` again.

You should not see that error after that. Keep in mind. `bundle exec` only uses gem libraries that are specified in your `Gemfile`.

Comment: turned out i had installed sailthru rather than sailthru-client.  just a dumb error.  ty.